# calabash-android: Is it possible to ignore the canned (pre-defined) steps?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, bdd, functional-testing, calabash-android

How can I force **calabash-android** to disregard and ignore the canned (pre-defined) steps in the

```
.../gems/calabash-android-0.5.2.pre1/lib/calabash-android/steps/
```

directory?

Is there a way other than deleting those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer should cover it for anyone in the same situation - [How to override a Calabash predefined step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480426/how-to-override-a-calabash-predefined-step/29487756#29487756)

Apparently the pre-canned steps may be distributed separately to the calabash gem going forwards, but for now you can override them or delete them by following the answer posted above.