# How to override a Calabash predefined step?

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios, calabash-android

I'm defining custom calabash steps (to use on both iOS and Android) and would like to selectively override various predefined steps. An example is:

```
Given /^I press the "([^\"]*)" button$/ do |text|
  tap_when_element_exists("android.widget.Button {text CONTAINS[c] '#{text}'}")
end
```

Instead of using this implementation, I would like to provide my own. If I define and use a step with a matching regex I get an error:

```
Ambiguous match of "I press the "big red" button"
```

It also suggests using "--guess" but that didn't help, and I still get the `Cucumber::Ambiguous` error.
I could make some arbitrary change to the regex for my step, ex:

```
I tap the "big red" button
```

But that feels like a poor solution for a few reasons

- Having to prevent usage of the built in step, especially since it may be the most natural phrasing
- If canned_steps adds a conflicting step in a future revision, I'd be forced to change my phrasing and all my scenarios

  - It also appears that the phrasing is a bit different between the Android and iOS predefined steps. If I can't override, this means I need to avoid using the iOS predefined steps on Android, even though I will **not** get the `Cucumber::Ambiguous` error on Android.
- In general I don't like to tell the scenario authors (often QA) to not use a particular phrasing, I would rather add alternate phrasing than remove options

Is there a way to un-define a built in step?  The [android canned_step documentation](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/canned_steps.md) suggests there should be: `You can add your own steps or change the ones you see here`

I don't want to lose ALL the predefined steps immediately either (ex: not require calabash_steps.rb). I'd rather phase them out only when they become a problem.
And I don't want to directly edit the calabash code if I can help it, as that would require rolling my own calabash distro instead of using gem to install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd rather phase them out only when they become a problem. And I don't want to directly edit the calabash code if I can help it, as that would require rolling my own calabash distro instead of using gem to install it.

In your `features/support/env.rb`, replace `require calabash-android/cucumber` with

```
require 'calabash-android/color_helper'
require 'calabash-android/operations'

World(Calabash::Android::ColorHelper)
World(Calabash::Android::Operations)
```

Then copy the calabash-android canned steps to a file in your project `features/step_definitions/canned_steps.rb`.

Remove or replace the predefined steps as needed.

And a heads up - we are working on Calabash 2.0:  a merge of the iOS and Android APIs.  We are talking about removing the pre-defined steps from the new `calabash` gem and distributing them as a separate gem. As an example have a look at the way [rspec](https://github.com/rspec) distributes behaviors as separate gems.  No decision has been made about this yet.

Comment: Can you share anything more on calabash 2.0? ETA?

Comment: There's really no way to undefine a step?

Comment: AFAIK No.  There is no way to undefine a step.

Comment: This works =) Applying to iOS was quite similar, but one replaces `require 'calabash-cucumber/cucumber'` with the contents of cucumber.rb minus calabash-steps.rb - see: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/blob/develop/calabash-cucumber/lib/calabash-cucumber/cucumber.rb

And then copy and modify calabash-steps.rb